Keycloak and new organization feature with multi membership on a user ( v26 )
I've been testing the organization feature with multiple organizations for a single user. However, when there are two organizations assigned to a user, the claims disappear from the access token. But if I assign only one organization to the user then the claims 'organization' appear correctly. Is there a current limitation of the feature ?
Else do you have any ideas on how to generate a dedicated access token for a specific organization ?

Can you share "the claims disappear" situation with two organizations example?

Did you find a soltion to this?

Check solution in: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/35581
